# A lot of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory objects residing in heap dump

Tags: java, spring

I am facing an OOM memory issue in a spring application deployed in tomcat server. On investigating the heap dump in the Eclipse MAT, I found that 4500 instances of **org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory** class are present which are occupying a significant amount of heap memory. These are also coming under the leak suspects.

`4,504 instances of "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory", loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader"`

Now, this might or might not lead to OOM. But shouldn't there be only one instance of **DefaultListableBeanFactory** class present in heap as we have only one application context?

What can be the reason of so many of **DefaultListableBeanFactory** objects in the heap?

Comment: Which version of spring are you using ?

Comment: I am using 3.1.1.RELEASE